# Abstract Algebra - Finite Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Let G be a non-trivial finite group. For every $a,b \in G$ that are not identities, there exist $c \in G$ such that $b=c^{-1}ac$. Show that $|G|=2$.

Comment: I think you can show that $b^n = c^{-1}a^nc$ for any $n$, then see what happens when you choose $b=a^2 \ne e$ assuming that $|G| \ge 3$

Comment: It boggles my mind that this was closed as off topic. It has five upvotes and two upvoted answers. It's solved. Deleting this question would do nothing but remove useful content from the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can answer this question as follows:
Define $a \equiv b$ if $\exists c $ such that $b=c^{-1}ac$. Note that this is an equivalence relation on the group $G$, and hence divides it into equivalence classes of the form $[a]=\{ c^{-1}ac\  | c \in G\}$. We are given that every $a$ and $b$ that are not identities  are such  that $a \equiv b$. Thus, the equivalence class of $a$ consists of all elements except the identity, so it's order is $|G|-1$.

Now the class equation comes to our rescue. What it basically says is that the size of the equivalence class divides the order of the group! So $|G|-1 $ divides $|G|$, and so $|G|=2$, since this is the only finite quantity with this property!

Please comment back if  you don't know the class equation: I can edit my answer later on!

Comment: Thank you so much. No need to explain the class equation :)

Comment: My pleasure. Would love to talk on length about the class equation later on.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to show that $G$ is abelian. Suppose not. Since every nonidentity element is conjugate to every other, every nonidentity element has the same order. By Cauchy's theorem this implies that $G$ must be of prime power order because otherwise there would be two elements whose orders are distinct primes.

Note that since $G$ is not abelian, there exists a nontrivial commutator element. It follows by the conjugacy condition and normality of the commutator subgroup that $G$ is perfect. But groups of prime power order are solvable, which gives us a contradiction. Thus $G$ is abelian, and since every nonidentity element is conjugate it must have order 2 if it is not trivial.